# Short way to turn JSON array data into a string in ruby

Tags: arrays, json, ruby

I get some data from an API and use `apidata = JSON.parse(response)` to parse the JSON. It looks like this:

```
> puts(apidata['values'])
{"a"=>{"value"=>"..."}, "b"=>"..."}
{"a"=>{"value"=>"..."}, "b"=>"..."}
{"a"=>{"value"=>"..."}, "b"=>"..."}
{"a"=>{"value"=>"..."}, "b"=>"..."}
[...]
```

I would like to create an array that contains only the values of `b` in all elements, so I can `.join()` it to a string.

This would work:

```
array = Array.new
for item in apidata['values']
    array.push(item['b'])
end
string = array.join(',')
```

But seems like a lot of code for a rather simple task. Is there a shorter way to do the exact same thing?

Comment: In Ruby we eschew `for` and use `each` and `map`. Why is a different question and well covered here and on the Internet. Instead of using `puts` to display `apidata['values']`, instead strip it down to a few elements and put the actual definition into the question. Doing otherwise forces us to reconstruct the variable/array which wastes our time and induces variability into the responses which is undesirable. "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to extract elements from an array into another array then a common Ruby idiom is [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map) instead of creating a new array and copying the entries yourself.

```
apidata['values'].map { |h| h['b'] }.join(',')
```